# blender's triangle is CW order or CCW order by default?

Tags: blender

I have a model exported from blender.

I checked and I found that each triangle is in the clock wise order. Is this the default order for blender?

Answer (score -4):

You can see the generation of triangles with "Ctrl+T" or Mesh>Faces>Triangulate Faces
There you get a triangulated mesh which will be the same as the exported order.

Basically the is no clock or counter clock wise. It all depends on your model's shape and how you rotate or even mirror it. But with the quads to tris you already see how your model will look after exporting without importing into another application (unless the application you import to changes the mesh).